# Arithmetic progression Find first term and common difference when sum of 10 terms and the 8th term is given

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Sigma is a car company that sell cars.

Sigma sells $x$ cars in the first month and its sales increase constantly by $y$ cars every subsequent month. It sells $96$ cars in the $8^{th}$ month and the total sales for the first $10$ months are $355$ cars. Find the value of $x$ and $y.$

Basically, this problem is finding the common difference and the first term of the arithmetic progression

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you show us any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck.  Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig i can't seem to relate the information given with what i have to find. All i know is the answer is x = 30 and y = 8

Comment: "They sell $96$ cars in their eighth month". How can you use $x$ and $y$ to express the number of cars sold the eighth month? They sell $x + 0y$ cars the first month, they sell $x + 1y$ cars the second month, they sell $x + 2y$ cars the third month, and so on...

Comment: You also know that $x + (x + y) + (x + 2y) + \cdots + (x + 9y) = 355$.

Comment: so is _10x + 45y = 355_  ?

Comment: The numbers you gave us don't seem to work. Double check please

Comment: @Saf  You obtain the equations $x + 7y = 96$ and $10x + 45y = 355$.  However, as Jeffrey L. recognized, that system of equations does not have integer solutions.  Is the question stated correctly?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig This is what made me confused. This is all what the question said. Basically, this question is not possible to solve with all the given information

Comment: If you want the solution $x = 30, y = 8$, then they sold $86$ cars in their eighth month, and they sold $660$ cars in total the first ten months.

Comment: @arthur Care explaining how that is possible? or how did you found out about it

Comment: We know that the equations are suppoed to be $x + 7y = \text{ something}$ and $10x + 45y = \text{ something else}$. Just insert $30$ instead of $x$ and $8$ instead of $y$, and you get the values you need for that to be a solution. For instance, $30 + 7\cdot 8 = 86$.